# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to be able to update my table using the codes that I tried but it always shows the error just like that

I tried the prepared statement but I don't know if I did it correctly.

So the code looks like this,

```
try{
    String sql = "update master.Employees set EmployeeName = '" + jTextField1.getText() + "'" + ",Address = '" + jTextField3.getText() + "'" + ",PhoneNumber = '" +
            jTextField4.getText() + "'" + ",EmailAddress = '" + jTextField5.getText() + "'" + "WHERE EmployeeID = " + jTextField1.getText();
    Statement update = myconObj.createStatement();
    update.executeUpdate(sql);
}
catch (SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i tried to enter the employee Id which is the primary key of my database to be able to update but it always shows the error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'INTEGER' cannot
>   hold values of type 'CHAR'.

I think I messed up the grab structure because it shows this one

```
¬í sr %org.netbeans.lib.ddl.impl.CreateTable¢”j ™   xr +org.netbeans.lib.ddl.impl.ColumnListCommand2›Œî]2)³ L columnst Ljava/util/Vector;xr )org.netbeans.lib.ddl.impl.AbstractCommandø8¦Œ·q•ª Z executionWithExceptionZ    newObjectL addpropst Ljava/util/Map;L formatt Ljava/lang/String;L nameq ~ L ownerq ~ L quoteStrq ~ L spect ,Lorg/netbeans/lib/ddl/DatabaseSpecification;xp pt :create table [{object.owner}.]{object.name}
(
    {columns}
)t  EMPLOYEESpppsr java.util.VectorÙ—}[€;¯ I capacityIncrementI elementCount[ elementDatat [Ljava/lang/Object;xp       ur [Ljava.lang.Object;ÎXŸs)l  xp   
sr %org.netbeans.lib.ddl.impl.TableColumn;¦±5‘b  I decsizeZ nullableI sizeI typeL checkeq ~ L constraintColumnsq ~ L defvalq ~ xr -org.netbeans.lib.ddl.impl.AbstractTableColumn¸Ô§y[k  Z   newColumnZ  newObjectL addpropsq ~ L cnameq ~ L formatq ~ L nameq ~ L otypeq ~ L refcolq ~ L reftabq ~ xppt 
EMPLOYEEIDt ³{column.name} {column.type}[({column.size}[,{column.decsize}])][ {column.type.suffix}][ default {default.value}][ {column.notnull}not null][ check ({check.condition})] primary keyt 
EMPLOYEEID_PKt PRIMARY_KEYpp        
   pppsq ~ pt EMPLOYEENAMEt §{column.name} {column.type}[({column.size}[,{column.decsize}])][ {column.type.suffix}][ default {default.value}][ {column.notnull}not null][ check ({check.condition})]q ~ t COLUMNpp       2   pppsq ~ pt ADDRESSq ~ q ~ q ~ pp       2   pppsq ~ pt PHONENUMBERq ~ q ~ q ~ pp       
   pppsq ~ pt EMAILADDRESSq ~ q ~ q ~ pp       2   pppsq ~ pt IMAGEq ~ q ~ !q ~ pp       2   pppppppx
```

Comment: Can you share your table's definition?

Comment: the table is created in the database within the netbeans and y primary key is the employeeID which is integere.

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements. Concatenating values into a query string is unsafe as it opens your code to SQL injection, and in addition it can cause all kinds of other errors.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to used `PreparedStatement` like below :

```
 try
      {
          String sql = "UPDATE `master.Employees` SET `EmployeeName`=?, `Address `=?, `PhoneNumber`=?, `EmailAddress`=? WHERE `EmployeeID `=?";
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         //putting value for all placeholder (?)
         ps.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());
         ps.setString(2,jTextField3.getText());
         ps.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
         ps.setString(4,jTextField5.getText());
         ps.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));

         int i=0;
         i = ps.executeUpdate();
         if(i>0)
             {
         //do   something   
             }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
      {

      e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Comment: Glad i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The function call `jTextField1.getText()` basically returns a `String` object and the database is expecting an integer. Try `Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())` instead.

Comment: I did what you said but, it shows the same error again

Comment: As @Mureinik suggested we will need to look at the DDL of the employees table.

Comment: uhm, i'm sorry but where can i find the DDL of my database in netbeans???

Comment: You will need to go to the services tab. Select on the database you are writing to and expand. Select the Tables folder and highlight the Employees table and right click. One option should be 'Grab Structure'.

Comment: I think i messed up that part

Comment: it might be easier to run the following code
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 System.out.println("No. of columns : " + rsmd.getColumnCount());
 System.out.println("Column name of 1st column : " + rsmd.getColumnName(1));
 System.out.println("Column type of 1st column : " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));

Comment: What values are you pushing into telephone number and employee number as both are ints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value of `jTextField1.getText ()`, to pass an `integer`.
You can do it in the following way before doing the update

```
int id = Integer.parseInt (jTextField1.getText ());
```

Comment: edit the question and put the DDL scheme as comments @Mureinik to help you better

Answer (score 0):

maybe other field is `Integer`, you can check `PhoneNumber` this is desgined by `Integer`?

Comment: Yes, the employeeId and phone number is integer

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be spacing.

instead of

`+ "WHERE EmployeeID = " + jTextField1.getText();`

you should write

`+ " WHERE EmployeeID = " + jTextField1.getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `''` from integer value phone number so that your code looks like this

```
String sql = "update master.Employees set EmployeeName = '" + jTextField1.getText() + "'" + ",Address = '" + jTextField3.getText() + "'" + ",PhoneNumber = " +
        jTextField4.getText() + " + ",EmailAddress = '" + jTextField5.getText() + "'" + "WHERE EmployeeID = " + jTextField1.getText();
Statement update = myconObj.createStatement();
```

Hint:

```
Char='123434'
Integer=12345
```